# Issue with listview scrollable

Tags: java, android, listview

i don't know why my list view doesn't scroll completely.

I show you also single list view item.XML about adapter's xml where i put the item for every rows of my `listview`, so i hope that you can help me!

Thanks everybody!

I show you pic!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ub2W.png

this is .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"


    >

 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
       android:layout_marginTop="0dp"

       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

> single_listview_item.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk_box"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ivImage"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk_box"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="This ia name"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/caratteristica"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk_box"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:text="This is caratteristica"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:text="10"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/valuta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:text="$"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/np"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what's your adapter's xml

Comment: @VishalVaishnav i updated code

Comment: Show your adapter code too

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter's xml , RelativeLayout tag ,write wrap_content replace of match_parent like below;

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: decrease your padding in xml

Comment: ok if i check only 1 checkbox but if i check 2 checkboxes i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your `single_listview_item.XML`'s `RelativeLayout` from `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Change your `ListView`'s height to `wrap_content` too